# What tools are suitable for modeling calculation dependencies

Tags: modeling, analytics, dependencies

Our team is developing engine that calculates more than 100 different (financial) numbers based on some formulas (mostly semi-complex sums, averages and ratios) in Java and SQL. We want to create model and visualization of the calculations to ease analysis and optimization process but we can not find a suitable tool/type of tools that would help.

We would especially like to capture in the model:

- inputs
- formulas
- auxiliary properties
- outputs
- dependencies between these objects

E.g if you have formula for calculating sales that needs data from two SQL tables and produces output to NoSQL storage using configuration from a REST service (auxiliary property), we need everything present and connected in graph. The we would like to analyse e.g. by clicking an input source and seeing what is using it. We are mainly aiming for optimization of data flow.

We tried UML component diagrams (closest hit), UML Class diagrams (overkill), Process diagrams (too much process oriented), ER diagrams (not covering enough), mind maps (dependencies are problematic) but nothing seemed suitable so far. Any suggestions/examples of type of tools that can help with this?